# How to get into Steam Directory

Tags: 13.04, directory, steam

I'm trying to add skins into Counter Strike Source but I don't know where the steam directory is. I also downloaded Steam from the Ubuntu Software Center. If anyone knows how to get into please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The Steam folder is located at

```
~/.local/share/Steam
```

if that doesn't exist, try

```
~/.steam
```